# Logging into mail server works through telnet but fails though imap(s) (Dovecot+MySQL)

Tags: email, debian, dovecot, imap, telnet

I have followed the [ISPMail tutorial](http://workaround.org/book/export/html/366%20ISPMail) on how to set up a Debian mail server.

I can log into the dovecot server through telnet like this:

```
[root@{hostname}: /home/{user}]# telnet {hostname}.{TLD} 143
Trying 127.0.1.1...
Connected to {hostname}.{TLD}.
Escape character is '^]'.
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE STARTTLS     AUTH=PLAIN] Dovecot ready.
1 LOGIN {user}@{hostname}.{TLD} {password}
1 OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE SORT SORT=DISPLAY     THREAD=REFERENCES THREAD=REFS MULTIAPPEND UNSELECT IDLE CHILDREN NAMESPACE UIDPLUS LIST-    EXTENDED I18NLEVEL=1 CONDSTORE QRESYNC ESEARCH ESORT SEARCHRES WITHIN CONTEXT=SEARCH LIST-    STATUS] Logged in
```

(Sidenote) should not these 2 commands be identical?

```
[root@{hostname}: /home/{user}]# telnet {hostname}.{TLD} imaps
Trying 127.0.1.1...
Connected to {hostname}.{TLD}.
Escape character is '^]'.
1 LOGIN {user}@{hostname}.{TLD} {password}
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

But when I try to access the server with a mailprogram (mutt) like this:

```
mutt -f imaps://{hostname}.{TLD}
Username at {hostname}.{TLD}: {user}@{domain}
Password for {user}@{domain}@{hostname}.{TLD}: {password}
Logging in.
Login failed.
Closing connection to {hostname}.{TLD}
```

Here is /var/log/mail.log:

```
Jan  2 00:50:55 {hostname} dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<{user}@{domain}>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.1.1, lip=127.0.1.1, secured
Jan  2 00:51:03 {hostname} dovecot: IMAP({user}@{domain}): Disconnected: Too many invalid IMAP commands. bytes=38/1284
Jan  2 00:51:26 {hostname} dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=127.0.1.1, lip=127.0.1.1, TLS handshaking: SSL_accept() failed: error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol
Jan  2 00:51:55 {hostname} dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (auth failed, 1 attempts): user=<{user}@{domain}>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.1.1, lip=127.0.1.1, TLS
Jan  2 00:52:15 {hostname} dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (auth failed, 1 attempts): user=<{user}>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.1.1, lip=127.0.1.1, TLS
```

Thunderbird and my iPhone' mail program can't login either.

What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Num-Lock / Num-Pad

the number pad or num-lock maybe causing problem in password and maybe difficult to spot. Use number keys on top of keyboard.

## Telnet

`IMAP`(IMAP4) port is 143. Traffic is in plain text. That why you can connect with telnet.

`IMAPS`(IMAP4 over SSL) port is 993. A SSL channel has to be established first. It is expecting SSL hand shake. That is why your telnet to `imaps` failed.

## Mutt

```
mutt -f imap://{hostname}.{TLD}
```

Test imap authentication, username, password with plain imap 1st. That let you know if the account is actually working or not.

```
mutt -f imaps://{hostname}.{TLD}
```

If imaps is setup properly with self-signed certificate, `mutt` will ask for certificate confirmation. You will have to option to `reject`, `accept once` or `accept always`.

## Thunderbird

To test IMAPS, use Thunderbird with manual config. If your dns is not fully setup, enter IP address of your imap server, pick IMAPS and port 993. When checking imaps email, it should pop up a window for accepting the self signed ssl cert.

Comment: It still fails. And I also need imaps and not imap.

Comment: It is very very difficult to test imaps with telnet, if not impossible. I will check mutt in an hour.

Comment: I updated the answer. I believe the probem is with self-signed cert., which mutt cannot handle. You can try with thunderbird.

Comment: Okay so I tried with the IP thing with thunderbird without luck. Also mutt does ask me to confirm the cert because of self signing so it seems mutt knows how to handle it. No luck yet with logging in. Can a missing MX record really be this fatal?

Comment: No, mx record affect email delivery(smtp), nothing to do with imap(s) or pop3.

Comment: Stop dovecot, then start it again. Check `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/mail.log` for dovecot start up message. See if there are any error or warning messages.

Comment: I tried `mutt -f imaps://` to one of my imap server with self-signed cert. It actually ask for confirmation for the cert. and I can selected permit permanently. Mutt version 1.5.21. on ubuntu.

Comment: Okay update: Did some verbose logging and passwords to the log etc. and found out that when I have tried logging in and I have numbers in my password, if I type the numbers with the numpad, they are not what I expected. TLDR: I can successfully login with mutt! BUT. This is useless because I need to be able to send/receive email with my iPhone as well as my windows machine which has Thunderbird. Any help?

Comment: I tailed /var/log/syslog while attempting to connect with Thunderbird. It gave me several lines like this:

Comment: `imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip={MY IP}, lip=192.169.2.33, TLS: SSL_read() failed: error:14094418:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert unknown ca`

Comment: @Akke The num-pad problem is only specific to your machine. I bet you will have no problem with your iPhone. And with Thunderbird, enter the password with number key on top of your keyboard(actually I expect your num-pad works normally in Windows), that may work also.

Comment: I might add: The mutt connection is local.

Comment: More info: iPhone connected successfully. What's wrong with thunderbird?

Comment: Those lines will show up before you accept the cert. in thunderbird. Close Thunderbird, open again, click inbox, the cert. windows should pop up (or pop under).

Comment: You welcome :) Happy 2013!!